# How to convert an N-level dict to yaml in TCL

Tags: tcl

So I understand from looking around at other answers on this site that this is tricky due to TCLs type system, but what I want to do is take some arbitrarily shaped dict, and convert it into a correctly formatted yaml that could then be read in by any yaml parser in any other language.

The motivation is a metadata system that users can read and write to over different sessions. Users themselves will know the structure of the data (as they made it), but the system itself won't.

So take the following multi-level dict:

```
set dict_sensor_status [dict create main ok recieve ok send ok]
set dict_sensor_1 [dict create power 100 signal 80 status $dict_sensor_status]
set dict_sensor_2 [dict create power 75 signal 80]
set dict_parent [dict create sensor_1 $dict_sensor_1 sensor_2 $dict_sensor_2]
puts $dict_parent

sensor_1 {power 100 signal 80 status {main ok recieve ok send ok}} sensor_2 {power 75 signal 80}
```

I would like that to create a correctly formatted yaml, like so:

```
sensor_1:
  power: 100
  signal: 80
  status:
    main: ok
    recieve: ok
    send: ok
sensor_2:
  power: 75
  signal: 80
```

From what I can see, the yaml library will just produce a single layer yaml with long strings something like this:

```
sensor_1: power 100 signal 80 status {main ok recieve ok send ok} 
sensor_2: power 75 signal 80
```

This is fine within tcl, as the users could treat that string as a dict and carry on their merry way, but if someone then tries to read this yaml in say python, it will not produce the correct result.

The huddle option seems to work for producing correctly formatted yamls, but the current infrastructure I have uses dicts so I'd rather not change everything.
Is there some way of doing this within tcl while keeping the data as a dict? Or is there some way to convert the dict to a huddle when writing out the yaml?
Or is this just a doomed endevour with dicts, and do I need to convert the code to use huddles over dicts.

EDIT: alternatively, I'm not married to the idea of a yaml file. And similarly structured file like json etc would work.

Comment: The problem is: how to tell `here "is a string"` from `here {is a list}` from `here {is a dict ionary}`. You need _something_ to describe the shape, and Tcl doesn't encourage using its internal types for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to JSON, the [rl_json package](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json) is *thoroughly* recommended as a production-grade system. For example:

```
package require rl_json

# Using arrays for convenience; there's several other approaches that would work too
array set s1 {
    power 100
    signal 80
    status,main ok
    status,rcv ok
    status,snd ok
}
array set s2 {
    power 75
    signal 80
}

puts [rl_json::json template {{
    "sensor_1": {
        "power": "~N:s1(power)",
        "signal": "~N:s1(signal)",
        "status": {
            "main": "~S:s1(status,main)",
            "recieve": "~S:s1(status,rcv)",
            "send": "~S:s1(status,snd)"
        }
    },
    "sensor_2": {
        "power": "~N:s2(power)",
        "signal": "~N:s2(signal)"
    }
}}]
```

That produces this output:

```
{"sensor_1":{"power":100,"signal":80,"status":{"main":"ok","recieve":"ok","send":"ok"}},"sensor_2":{"power":75,"signal":80}}
```

There's several other ways to build the output.

---

Doing the equivalent for YAML seems to be… complex. These are the two packages you'll need:

- [yaml package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/yaml.html)
- [huddle package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/huddle.html)

There doesn't seem to be any package like rl_json that wraps up all the complexity nicely.

Comment: I _believe_ you can feed in a dictionary to `json template`. I just don't usually do my data binding like that…

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. If not I'll just resign myself to using huddles which seem to the job.

Comment: Although I guess the question remains as to why that would work where the yaml doesn't? Presumably all the limitations with [dict create a "b c d e"] would remain? How does the rl_json package know that "b c d e" is a string or a dict?

Comment: It knows… because it's been told in the template that the bit here is a string (`~S:`), the bit there is a number (`~N:`), and (not used in this case) the bit in the other place is a JSON fragment (`~J:`). The trick to the rl_json package is that it effectively turns JSON into a “native datatype”; the code's optimised to scale up to very large documents.

Comment: There's nothing equivalent for YAML mainly because nobody's written one.